# Why use async/await in an action in controller in Asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

Action in Controller is already in a different thread, why do we still need to use async/await? 
I was looking at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-posttodoitem-create-method
I see it has a action in this controller: 
[HttpPost]
public async Task> PostTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)

So, I did a few test in my own controller, I see when I send a request from my browser, the server side always create a new worker thread to handle the request, so that's why I had the doubt: if the controller is already handling request in different thread, why should I still use async/await?  Since the request being handled in a new thread, I don't think it will block any other request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *async and await pattern* is about scalability. Why block a thread when you can use an IO completion port? It's as simple as that.

The *async and await pattern* offloads the work (term used loosely) and allows the threadpool to potentially recover the thread and use it elsewhere until your *IO work* completes.

You might not notice a difference now, but when you start to scale a website to 1000s of concurrent jobs, efficiently using resources will start to matter a lot. One of those tools you can use, is... the *async and await pattern*.

<sub>***Note** : this is a simplistic response to a simplistic question on a complex and nuanced topic. Without writing a thesis on the internal workings of a language feature and its uses, it's probably a good place for you to start researching the async and await pattern to answer some of the most common questions for your self, you'll have fun and gain a sense of achievement :)*</sub>